# C# UML diagram interpretation

Tags: c#, uml

i dot an understanding question, im new in programming c# and dont know if i interpreted the uml right.

My suggestion for class Tree:

```
public class Tree<T>:Elements{

public int create(){
   //code
   return 1;
}


public int invicible(){
    return 1;
    //code

}


}
```

Am i on the right way?

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: You can not follow the diagram since it's not UML (at least no legal one).

Answer (score 1):

The diagram does not follow UML notation, so it is difficult to say how to implement it in C#.

You consider *Tree* to be a generic class, but this is not the case in the diagram. The UML notation for `class Tree<T> ... {...}` is  :

[image]

Also the used arrow does not represent a generalization/realization, and this enforced by the presence of the multiplicity "*" even it is strangely placed.

Even that does not follow UML notation note also in diagram there is `<T extends Element>` not compatible with your inheritance, but specifying a restriction to *T*

Comment: @du7ri who given you that diagram ? are you sure it is theoretically UML ?